# Reading PDF's with text, handwritten signatures, and box fills

Tags: r, pdf, tensorflow, jpeg

I haven't seen any type of answer to this question on stackoverflow or after google searching.

What R Packages would I have to use to read a PDFs into R that contains hand written signatures and boxes that have been filled in?

I have a large data set of PDFs which are pretty much surveys asking for standard things. Name, number, home address, signature...a good example of what these pdfs look like are Mass Health Applications https://www.mass.gov/files/2017-08/app.pdf.

1) Are there packages for R that can read PDFs with signatures or box fill ins?

2) Would I have to save these PDFs in some other format, maybe jpeg?

Comment: Is your goal to "read" the signature somehow or skip over it?

Comment: Some pdfs have the signatures/boxes filled sections left blank. Goal is to read signatures/boxes and create some type of count as to how many pdfs have signatures/boxes filled.

Comment: Don't know about handwriting but if you want to read electronically filled pdf forms you can use `staplr::get_fields`. Otherwise, if handwritten bits are parsed as text, you can use `pdftools::pdt_text`. If nothing works, you can convert pdf to an image using `animation::im.convert` and extract the siganutre box, using some heuristics to see if anything's written in it

Comment: correction: `pdftools::pdf_text`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're working with a large number of documents with the same handwriting, OCR technology isn't advanced enough to turn signatures into machine-readable characters. Computer vision isn't there yet. Your best bet might be to hire a firm to manually transcribe the bulk information.